# Querying two tables in a database with Java

Tags: java, sql, database

I have been defeated by the great SQL boss and am now requesting assistance.

**Ive removed spaces in table names to avoid confusion**

Anyways, I have two tables Orders and Order Details. I need to query a few columns from both. So far, I can query Orders just fine, but when it comes to querying Order Details, or the two together, I get errors.

My Question is this: How do I query two tables?
(note: semicolon is at the bottom, imagine it's there)

Here's what works so far on Orders:

```
String queryString = "select `Order Date`, Freight "
                   + "from Orders "
                   + "where Orders.`Order ID` = ? "
```

Here's my attempt to just grab one column from Order Details and the error to follow

```
String queryString = "select Product "
                   + "from `Order Details` "
                   + "where `Order Details`.`Order ID` = ? "
```

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: ORDER DETAILS.ORDER ID
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:528)
```

Here's my attempt to grab both at once and the error to follow

```
String queryString = "select `Order Date`, Freight, Product "
                   + "from Orders, `Order Details` "
                   + "where Orders.`Order ID` = ? "
```

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: PRODUCT
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:528)
```

Here's the above attempt with an extra line at the bottom combining them (I don't know what this does), but it alters the error.

```
String queryString = "select `Order Date`, Freight, Product "
                   + "from Orders, `Order Details` "
                   + "where Orders.`Order ID` = ? "
                   + "and Orders.`Order ID` = `Order Details`.`Order ID`"
```

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: ORDER DETAILS.ORDER ID
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:528)
```

Comment: EIther the user can't access the columns, or they don't exist. That's basically what the error messages tell you. I'd start by renaming all your tables and columns to avoid spaces in them, and thus allowing to query them without backticks.

Comment: The immediate issue is that you are referring to objects in the database that don't exist.

Comment: I mean the table definitely exists though. I changed the name to avoid spaces and it still doesn't exist, but orders table exists. makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: if the table/column really exists (with exactly the correct name, same schema,...) then the 2nd alternative of the error message may apply: lacks privilege

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That's what absolutely BLOWS my mind. I can access the OrderDetails (no spaces right now) table, and I can access say the quantity of the product the ordered, but when I change it to product, I get errors.

Comment: column name correct? eventually some extra hidden character (space)? (I don't think Product is a reserved name, but maybe use backticks there too or/and together with table name...) - I also find it helpful to try SQLs on the database own console program first [[and avoid spaces in names (table, columns, ...) - it's cause to lots of trouble]]

Comment: is the first error really "lacks privilege or object not found: ORDER DETAILS.ORDER ID"? is it 'ORDER ID' that is missing/wrong?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes it is correct. I'm just going to ask my professor tonight, this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the table name in quotes doesn't work in any SQL-Server i know without changing some configuration.
The correct way is using `[]`:

MSSQL-Example:

```
SELECT * FROM [Order Details]
```

Your query may look like this:

```
String queryString = "SELECT Product "
+ "FROM [Order Details] "
+ "WHERE `Order ID` = ? "
```

But i would suggest to work without whitspaces within any identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Read about JOIN statements, this will allow you to work with two tables. Try use something like “SELECT your_columns FROM orders o JOIN orderDetails od ON o.id = od.order_id”. 
Errors like “object not found” means you didn’t create table. Wish it’ll help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.